# Save data using php and MySQL

Tags: php, android, sql

This is my android program. I want to save `id=1` and `name=0` into the database first.  Then when I click a button again, it will become `id=1` and `name=1`. But my database still shows `id=1` and `name=0` even when I use count++. Why is `name=0` and not `name=1`?

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

 public class  AndroidTestActivity  extends Activity {
 JSONArray jArray;
 String result = null;
 InputStream is = null;
 StringBuilder sb=null;
 private int mCount= 0;

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

     b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
          @Override

          public void onClick(View v) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          ArrayList nameValuePairs = new ArrayList();
          mCount++;
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id","1"));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",Integer.toString (mCount)));

          //http post
          try{
               HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
               HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.132/insert.php");
               httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
               HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);

          }catch(Exception e){
               Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
          }
         }
       });
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are increasing the count after getting the name. You need to do it before:

```
mCount++;
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id","1"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",Integer.toString (mCount)));
```